# switch over value of enum: case expressions must be constant expressions

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

I have an enum with the following structure:

```
public enum Friends {
    Peter("Peter von Reus", "Engineer"),
    Ian("Ian de Villiers", "Developer"),
    Sarah("Sarah Roos", "Sandwich-maker");

    private String fullName;
    private String occupation;

    private Person(String fullName, String occupation) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return this.fullName;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return this.occupation;
    }
}
```

I would now like to use `switch` to determine, if a variable `name` is associated with a certain `enum`:

```
//Get a value from some magical input
String name = ...

switch (name) {
    case Friends.Peter.getFullName():
        //Do some more magical stuff
        ...
    break;
    case Friends.Ian.getFullName():
        //Do some more magical stuff
        ...
    break;
    case Friends.Sarah.getFullName():
        //Do some more magical stuff
        ...
    break;
}
```

This seems perfectly legal to me, but I'm getting the error `case expressions must be constant expressions` in Eclipse. 
I can get around this with a simple set of if statements but I would like to know the reason for this error and how things might go south if this was allowed.

NOTE: I cannot change the structure of `Friends`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> This seems perfectly legal to me

Well it's not - a method call is *never* a constant expression. See [JLS 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) for what constitutes a constant expression. And a case value always has to be a constant expression.

The simplest fix would be to have a `Friend.fromFullName` static method, which perhaps looked the `Friend` up in a `HashMap<String, Friend>`. (You don't *have* to have that method in `Friend` of course... it's just that would be the most conventional place.) Then you could switch over the enum rather than the name.

As a side note, your enum name should be in the singular and with `ALL_CAPS` members, so `Friend.PETER` etc.

Answer (score 29):

If I understand your question, you can use `valueOf(String)` like

```
String name = "Peter";
Friends f = Friends.valueOf(name);
switch (f) {
case Peter:
    System.out.println("Peter");
    break;
case Ian:
    System.out.println("Ian");
    break;
case Sarah:
    System.out.println("Sarah");
    break;
default:
    System.out.println("None of the above");
}
```

Also, this

```
private Person(String fullName, String occupation) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.occupation = occupation;
}
```

Should be

```
private Friends(String fullName, String occupation) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.occupation = occupation;
}
```

Because `Person` != `Friends`.

**Edit**

Based on your comment, you will need to write a static method to get the correct `Friends` instance,

```
    public static Friends fromName(String name) {
        for (Friends f : values()) {
            if (f.getFullName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                return f;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Then you can call it with,

```
    String name = "Peter von Reus";
    Friends f = Friends.fromName(name);
```

`valueOf(String)` will match the name of the enum field. So "Ian", "Sarah" or "Peter".

Comment: No, because the name would be "Peter von Reus", not "Peter".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch why can you access the enum members in the case statement without the enum name before it (PETER instead of FRIENDS.PETER)?

Comment: Because the static method is in the enum.