# java enum pass array as a second parameter ot the construction

Tags: java, enums

Easy

```
public enum AvailableTestServices {
        UserContext("userContext", ["userURI"]), Level0and1ForUser("level0and1ForUser", ["userURI"]);
    private String serviceName;
    private String[] requiredParameters;

    private AvailableTestServices(String serviceName,
            String[] requriedParameters) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.requiredParameters = requriedParameters;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return serviceName;
    }
    public String[] getRequiredParameters(){
        return this.requiredParameters;
    }
}
```

I get an exception on the `,` that is in :

```
UserContext("userContext", ["userURI"]), Level0and1ForUser("level0and1ForUser", ["userURI"]);
```

the error is:

> Syntax error on token ",", Expression expected after this token AvailableTestServices.java /

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) in order to fully understand how arrays work and what's the proper way to instantiate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to do it should be the following:

```
UserContext("userContext", new String[]{"userURI"}),
Level0and1ForUser("level0and1ForUser", new String[]{"userURI"});
```

Comment: well that solved the problem but i am not able to do `AvailableTestServices.UserContext` why please ?

Comment: case expressions must be constant expressions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25183754/switch-over-value-of-enum-case-expressions-must-be-constant-expressions

Answer (score 2):

There is no syntax like this `["Text"]` for creating an array. This is the correct way:

```
public enum AvailableTestServices {
    UserContext("userContext", new String[] { "userURI" }), Level0and1ForUser("level0and1ForUser",
            new String[] { "userURI" });
    private String serviceName;
    private String[] requiredParameters;

    private AvailableTestServices(String serviceName, String[] requriedParameters) {
        this.serviceName = serviceName;
        this.requiredParameters = requriedParameters;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return serviceName;
    }

    public String[] getRequiredParameters() {
        return this.requiredParameters;
    }
}
```